# (Materialize CSS Framework) 'required' attribute does not work in materialize select tag

Tags: html, css, materialize

This is the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="input-field col s5 col m5">
   <select required id="passengerDestination" name="passengerDestination{{ $i }}" class="validate">
        <option selected="" disabled="" value="">Select Destination</option>
        <option selected="" disabled="" value="">Select value</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option>...</option>
    </select>
    <label class="white-text" for="passengerDestination">Destination</label>
 </div>
```

Please don't mind the `{{ $i }}` because I am using Laravel and the select tag is inside the @for loop.

The problem is that when I changed the class of the select tag to `browser-default` it triggers the **required** attribute of the select tag.

But that is not the thing I want. I want to use `require` attribute of the select tag without using the class `browser-default`.

How can this be done?

Material Framework used:

> materializecss.com

Answer (score 0):

The select you are seeing is a representation of the hidden, underlying native select. If you or some other code changes the native select, you need to call

```
$('{your selector}').material_select();
```

This will rebind the representation to the native select.

Comment: What I did was this:
`$('select').material_select()`
It does not let the the required attribute to function.